# Книги по C++

Tags: c++, книги

Здравствуйте, во втором семестре у меня начинается объектно-ориентированное программирование на C++ и хотелось бы узнать насчет книг. Что бы вы посоветовали?

Answer (score 2):

вот огромная отсортированная библиотека [тык](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3693656)

так же когда прочтёшь про классы,шаблоны,перегрузку операторов и т.д. то посмотри вот эти 2 семестра [тык 1](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3913069) [тык 2](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4086065)

сам учился по книге шилдта "С++ базовый курс" (но её многие ругают)

читал выдержки из страуструпа "Язык программирования С++" (очень хорошая книга)

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Еще вот [здесь](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-48036.html) есть довольно обширный список литературы по С++ с отзывами читавших людей.