# Первые шаги в изучении GUI в С++

Tags: c++, gui

Вот начал изучать всем известный язык С++. Работа с консолей не было самым сложным этапом. Все давалось очень легко ибо до этого языка программирования имел опыт работы.

Писал и тетрис и змейку в консоли. Все это очень прикольно, но хотелось бы не просто чёрный экрна, а что то больше, графический интерфейс, кнопочки всякие ну и т.п.

Так вот, я слышал, что есть много библиотек таких как:

1. OpenGL
2. DirectX
3. SDL

Ну и другие. Что еще слышал об *Qt*, что стоит с него начинать. Так вот, собственно вопрос:

*С чего лучше начать?*

Может у кого-то есть литература или видео-уроки.

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Так вам что именно нужно? Изучить кресты, или научиться делать всяческие...пардон, гуёвины (это от слова GUI, не подумайте плохого)?

Если второе, то C++ вряд ли можно назвать идеальным выбором для этого. Если первое, то лучше сконцентрироваться на возможностях самого языка, а конкретные задачи ставить себе уже по мере изучения. Что касается книг, то посмотрите ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184539/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c)

А вот что касается упомянутых вами библиотек, то они прямого отношения к ремеслу клепания окошек не имеют. Это библиотеки по работе с графикой. Если нет достаточных знаний языка и веских причин с ними связываться, то я бы на вашем месте не торопился в них углубляться, еще успеете

Answer (score 6):

Если ты хочешь "графический интерфейс, кнопочки всякие ну и т.п.", то есть GUI, то советую на Qt или gtk посмотреть (оба кроссплатформенны).

А что касается перечисленных OpenGL, DirectX и SDL - так это ведь графические библиотеки, их совместно с gui используют (встраивается виджет с выводом графики, как, например, QGLWidget), так что это немного другое. Но всё равно лучше бы OpenGL (а SDL в связке с ним часто используют для некоторых действий).

В итоге получится что-то вроде Qt+OpenGL (хотя есть модули Qt3D и QtOpenGL, что тоже использует OpenGL).

Answer (score 6):

OpenGL, DirectX и SDL это библиотеки для работы с 2Д/3Д графикой. Это не для GUI. Точнее графический интерфейс пользователя (GUI) там можно отрисовать, конечно, но это  применение не по назначению данных технологий (=забивать гвозди микроскопом)

ГУИ это QT, GTK  (как уже сказано выше - кросплатформенные библиотеки) или MFC например (WIN32) или прямое WINAPI. Последние только под винду и с учётом последних веяний этой платформы (смотри Windows 8) не шибко полезно вкладываться в их изучение так как скорее всего от них откажутся окончательно.

Answer (score 1):

Господа, я думаю, вы мне простите, что я выкопал эту тему, но пройти мимо я не мог.

Я занимаюсь разными GUI много лет и кое что об этом знаю.

В области GUI есть много крутых контор, которые делают свои решения, но я бы остановился на трех из них:

Telerik Controls, DevExpress и Nevron.

Специально не привожу ссылок, потому что в гугле ссылки по этим ключевым словам исчисляются миллионами.

Коротко о каждом:

**Telerik Controls** - без сомнения, современный лидер среди коммерческих компонентов. Во первых, они впереди планеты всей по веб-компонентам. Во вторых, я даже не могу придумать, какую область они не покрыли собой: WPF, ASP.NET Core, UWP, WinForms, SilverLight (да покоится с миром), Xamarin - для ЛЮБОЙ платформы в известной части вселенной у них есть продукт.

Список их пользователей включает Kodak, ООН, Microsoft, Heinz, Евросоюз, Accenture, Pfizer, Мировой Банк, Intel, Citigroup, NASA, Siemens, Nike, IMF, T-Mobile, Reuters, Вооруженные силы США, Vodafone, NBC, Universal Harvard University, Motorola

**DevExpress** - это паровоз, который мчится вперед на скорости больше 100 км в час. Еще 10 лет назад это был скромный набор компонентов для виндовс. Но с тех пор они каждый год выпускали новую версию, и сейчас это БОГАТЕЙШИЙ набор контролов, которые с минимумом кода позволяют решить практически любую задачу. Кроме того, они весьма удачно пару лет назад распользлись на MacOS, и теперь две платформы, которые вообще АССОЦИИРУЮТСЯ с GUI покрыты ими. Ну, и WEB - компоненты у них на высоте. Судя по скорости развития - они так хороши, что если бы не конкуренты - они бы захватили мир.

**Nevron** - когда то очень крутой набор компонентов, но сейчас они немного сдулись.  По моему, они не расползаются на другие платформы, как двое вышеназванных, а остаются верны WinForms. Но хорошее впечатление о себ оставили, и сейчас они по монему в весовой категории "бедненько, но чистенько".

И еще два замечания:

1) вообще говоря, при работе с такими компонентами - язык вторичен. То есть, компоненты представляют из себя "черные ящики с ручками", а из какого языка и как за эти ручки дергать - вопрос другого порядка. Конечно, у всех них есть рекомендуемые сочетания с языками программирования, но про это лучше уже читать на сайтах производителей.

(тс-с, я вам этого не говорил, но сейчас макcимум совместимости при разработке в винде - с языком C#)

2) Есть огромное кол-во не коммерческих, а "свободных" компонентов. И у сторонников "свободных" компонентов есть свои лидеры и прочее.

(Но я смотрел - и если коротко, то это "жалкое подобие левой руки". Но это, конечно же, моё частное мнение.)