# Какими GUI-библиотеками пользоваться на языке C++?

Tags: c++, gui, поиск-библиотек

Появилось желание попробовать уже применить свои знания в языке С++ (изучаю его только), но хотелось бы не просто в консоли, а сразу параллельно изучать и библиотеку в которой производится наиболее большое количество современных программ. Отсюда возник вопрос, какой лучше пользоваться?

И еще незначительный вопрос, вот скажите, с помощью чего мог быть создан следующий лаунчер - (https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2018/08/8b7f69838e52f5508f2b1ec71f83dd0d.png) Увидел его у младшего брата, понравился глазу и в использовании.

Comment: Любыми. Наиболее большое количество программ С++ обходится без пользовательского интерфейса, на втором месте CLI. С помощью чего угодно.

Comment: Скачай программку DiE или PEiD чтобы посмотреть с помощью чего сделано. Если навешан протектор или пакер, придётся его сначала снять, чтобы увидеть... Так же можно в любом отладчике увидеть по коду (при определённом опыте сразу видно)

Comment: Qt наиболее популярный C++-фреймворк для создания графических интерфейсов. На чём создана конкретная программа можно узнать посмотрев её файлы. Dota Changer, вероятно, сделана с помощью WPF (C#).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроcа: [Первые шаги в изучении GUI в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262566/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-gui-%d0%b2-%d0%a1)